# "Enable split view mode" option is missing in Skype in year 2022

Tags: skype

I would like to turn on the split view in Skype 8.89.0.403 (year 2022).
Everybody in Internet suggests to tick "Enable split view mode", but for me this option is simply missing. There are options:

- Settings
- Help and feedback
- Keyboard shortcuts
- Sign out

but no "Enable split view mode".

[image: More context menu]

What to do? I don't like this huge window.

Answer (score 4):

As Julia B. said, this feature was removed since Skype version 8.97.

To restore and preserve the feature, you need to download previous version from official website: https://download.skype.com/s4l/download/win/Skype-8.96.0.409.exe (Windows) or https://download.skype.com/s4l/download/mac/Skype-8.96.0.409.dmg (Mac OS).

Then you need to uninstall the latest version you have now and install the downloaded version.

Then you need to disable updates. As I am Windows user, I can only share instructions for Windows and hope somebody can help with Mac OS in comments. So in Windows, you need to go to the folder (whichever is present on your computer)

C:\Users\< username >\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop

or

C:\Users\< username >\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype

and remove the file "Skype-Setup.exe" from there. After that immediately create a folder named "Skype-Setup.exe" also there which will replace the file and block from it being created again by Microsoft updates.

Now you should have working version 8.96 with Split View feature present.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. Incomprehensible that Microsoft is removing the ability to chat in windows from a Windows program again. The reason is probably that phones don't use windows and Microsoft can't be bothered to maintain something like this for desktop users only.

Answer (score 1):

It was in ver. 8.96, gone again in ver.8.97. Look for 8.96 - it is available on the net for ddownload.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux/ this might help. Here listed old versions as well. Also I putted in here with few weeks availability
https://we.tl/t-thEHXxIZoH

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think this feature was removed. If you want it together with other cool integration features, I would suggest trying the UWP version of Skype.

I archived a large amount of older versions, I'd suggest version 14 as it is the last version that uses Windows 10's acrylic and reveal effects: [Skype 14 Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lTv34oxrYbzCfpBLB2JDk_HzwbyJEkgb/view?usp=share_link)

If you want a more up to date UWP version, version 15 is also a good option: [Skype 15 Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n63VFY2IAvj-Ph0jghgX7ioegOQ2BIH6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't have UWP. Actually I am thinking about removing Skype completely. If they make a complete shit out of it, I'll do so.

Comment: There are probably many older Win32 versions of Skype online, I'd suggest using Uptodown for that as they usually have a very large list of versions to choose from: https://skype.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions